# How to compress a React Project using gzip or brotli without using webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, compression

I have a react project which doesn't use webpack to bundle its files. Its a docker application which uses nginx to serve static files on production server. All the resources available on internet use webpack's [CompressorPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/) to compress the bundled build files. How do I compress the bundle using `brotli` or `gzip` while continuing to run the application without webpack?

Comment: Normally the web server compresses the files upon request...

Comment: I am confused - u compress bundle the same way as u compress any other file... e.g. gzip app.js -- what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using webpack, you will have to manually compress the files before deploying it to the server.

One of the programs you can use is [Peazip](https://peazip.github.io/brotli-compression-utility.html). This can help you with what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wish to compress the bundled build and configure nginx to serve the data from compress build.

Comment: @RitikSaxena Sounds like over-engineering. How large is your app? Where are compressed/decompressed files will be stored? How the permissions are handled: before compression, during and after decompression? Is there another underlying issue why you want to compress the actual executables? Feels like a potential security issue you'd want to avoid. It's not a standard functionality of a web server.